# Google Play Game Services C++ integration

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x

Sorry For My Bad English

I am new in cocos2d-x, i am trying to develop an application uses the google game services, I installed my environment with cocos2d-x 3.4 and NDKr10c
I followed the steps of this [solution](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/google-play-services-c-integration-problem/17008)
but I have a problem in the InitServices method
I have two errors in logcat of eclipse

- 03-13 01: 56: 44,623 E / GamesNativeSDK (6816): Can not register
  class com / google / android / gms / games / snapshot /
  SnapshotContents: an exception occurred.
- 03-13 01: 56: 44,659 E / GamesNativeSDK (6816): Could not register
  one or more required Java classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, i made an update on google play services